# One ARM-template for Azure database for MySQL and Postgresql?

Tags: json, azure, azure-resource-manager

Im currently trying to write an ARM-template which should include both MySQL and PostgreSQL in the deploy.json file and then have two separate parameters file, one for postgreSQL and one for MySQL.

I've started on a template but it does not work the way I want it too and I cant figure out why. In the template I have both Microsoft.DBforMySQL/servers and Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/servers.

```
"resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.DBforMySQL/servers",
      "apiVersion": "2017-12-01",
      "name": 
      "location": 
      "sku": {
        "name": 
      },
      "properties": {
            "version": 
            "administratorLogin": 
            "administratorLoginPassword": 
            "createMode": 
            "sslEnforcement": 
            "storageProfile": {
                "storageGb": 
                "backupRetentionDays": 
                "geoRedundantBackup": 
            }
      }
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/servers",
        "apiVersion": "2017-12-01",
        "name": 
        "location": 
        "sku": {
          "name": 
        },
        "properties": {
              "apiVersion": 
              "administratorLogin": 
              "administratorLoginPassword":
              "createMode": 
              "sslEnforcement": 
              "storageProfile": {
                  "storageGb": 
                  "backupRetentionDays":
                  "geoRedundantBackup": 
        }
    },
```

The output I want to achieve is that when you use for example "Postgre-parameter" file it should deploy a PostgreSQL database and read the resource "Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/servers" and vice versa. Is this possible or should I stop trying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is possible, but not magically (which you seem to think it should do). you have to code for it. easiest way to do that is by adding conditions to resources:

```
"resources": [
    {
        "condition": "[equals(parameters('postgres'), true)]"
        ...
    },
    {
        "condition": "[equals(parameters('mysql'), true)]"
        ...
    },
]
```

you'd also have to map values from your parameters to the resources.

Syntax: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-authoring-templates

Comment: Thanks for answering, im still very new to Azure and working with ARM-templates (which you maybe could have guessed) and I am trying my best to learn how to work with it :) Figured out the best way to learn is to ask a lot of questions.

Comment: you can consult this example for postgres: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-webapp-managed-postgresql/azuredeploy.json#L160. you can find mysql in the same repo